# display only selected results from a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, presentation

I have a table query that returns results that has some common information.
Also some data is created from the results of the query with php. I would like be able to select what is presented and the order.
Should I store the results in an array and present them after the 'foreach loop' or is there a better way?

Currently each row is presented for each record returned.
For example:

Row1 is presented:

```
Site (Name): ACT:CUST:PARL
CLLI (node code): 31B0
Family Name: Remote Studio
Region (state): ACT
Chassis: 01-31B0:P:ACT:cust:PARLIAMENT
Transmission Type: CPE
Vlan Number: 12

IP Address: 10.72.136.136
Multicast Address Range: 239.76.100.0/24
Location: 1 Capital, Capital Hill

Itam name / Itam Status 01-31b0-p-act-cust-parliament / Deployed
```

Row2 is presented:

```
Site (Name): ACT:cust:PARL
CLLI (node code): 31B0
Family Name: Remote Studio
Region (state): ACT
Chassis: 01-31B0:S:ACT:cust:PARLIAMENT
Transmission Type: CPE
Vlan Number: 13

IP Address: 10.72.137.8
Multicast Address Range: 239.76.100.0/24
Location: 1 Capital Circle, Capital Hill

Itam name / Itam Status 01-31b0-s-act-cust-parliament / Deployed
```

Wanted presentation:

```
(some other table data not developed yet)
Vlan Number: 12
Vlan Number: 13
Site (Name): ACT:CUST:PARL
CLLI (node code): 31B0
Family Name: Remote Studio
Region (state): ACT
Location: 1 Capital Circle, Capital Hill

Chassis: 01-31B0:P:ACT:CUST:PARLIAMENT
IP Address: 10.72.136.136
IP Address: 10.72.136.136
Multicast Address Range: 239.76.100.0/24

(some other data from another table/query)

Itam name / Itam Status 01-31b0-p-act-cust-parliament / Deployed 
Itam name / Itam Status 01-31b0-s-act-cust-parliament / Deployed
```

Display code:

```
        foreach($rows as $row){

        extract($row);


        //Get Transmission Type
if ($systype >3){
    $txtype="CPE";
    $famname="Remote Studio";
}else{
    $txtype="CORE";
    $famname="Core";
    }       





//convert int to chg status
$getstatus=new functions();
$getstatus->obj="$ASSETLIFECYCLESTATUS";
$ASSETSTATUS=$getstatus->listchangestatus();


//Get state
$sarr=$fn->getnode($system_name);
#$var_dump($sarr);
$region=$sarr[3];

?>

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-9" >
            <label>Site (Name): </label>
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$site_id";?>
            </span>
            <br />

            <label>CLLI (node code): </label>
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$site_code";?>
            </span>
            <br />

            <label>Family Name: </label>
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$famname";?>
            </span>
            <br />

            <label>Region (state): </label>
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$region";?>
            </span>
            <br />

            <label>Chassis: </label>    
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$system_name";?>
            </span>         
            <br />

            <label>Transmission Type: </label>  
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$txtype";?>
            </span>
            <br />  

            <label>Vlan Number: </label>    
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$vlan_id";?>
            </span>
            <br /><br />

            <label>IP Address: </label> 
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$ip_add_c";?>
            </span>         
            <br />

            <label>Multicast Address Range:</label>
            <span style="display:inline-block">
            <?php echo "$mcast/24";?>
            </span>
            <br />  

            <label>Location: </label>   
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$sys_loc";?>
            </span>
            <br /><br />

            <label>Itam name / Itam Status </label> 
            <span style="display:inline-block"> 
            <?php echo "$ASSETID / $ASSETSTATUS";?>
            </span>
            <br /><br />
</div>
</div>
       <?php
  }


  }else{
   echo "Error";
  }
```

Comment: Post the code you use to format the results: the answer is there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking - I have updated original post with code generation and display. I am using bootstrap framework.

Comment: I don't understand well: which is the problem? You have to simply rearrange fields on the page in the HTML. Where are you having troubles?

Comment: The problem is some fields I don't want repeated inside the while loop, and others rearranged (which I understand - the rearranging of HTML).
I think that I need to store them (in a multidimensional??) array and then I can display / reuse each field after the loop has completed. Is this the best way?

Comment: Or you may simply write the values... It depends... There isn't a best way... I don't know which are those fields, which ones you would like to omit... I know nothing :) This question seems to be a little broad...

Comment: The concept is: you have your variables available immediately: you don't necessarily need a new array. Maybe you can calculate new values directly in the foreach loop if all the needed variables for the calculations are yet present.